# Problem with the Derivative Operator (')

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, education

I was working through some physics equations and came to a dead stop when I couldn't get the `Derivative` operator to work on equations with 2 variables. An example I striped the problem down to is below. What subtle coding principal am I missing about symbolics? I have the documentation open on the other screen and it's not exactly clear how to work with pairs as inputs to functions. I looked at everything with `Fullform` and didn't see anything too unexpected. Is there an explanation as to what's going on?

```
h[h_] := h^2 + 2 h +3
h'[u]
```

> 2+2 u

(returns as expected)

```
f[{x_,y_}] := x^4 + y^4
Derivative[1][f][{x,y}]    
f'[{x,y}]
```

> f′[{x,y}]
>
> f′[{x,y}]

Comment: Better use `D` for total derivatives, e.g. `D[f[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 1}]` and `D[f[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 2}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a function has 2 arguments (not a single list argument), use:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^4 + y^4
Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y]
Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y]
```

> 4 x^3
>
> 4 y^3

Comment: Ah. So I was miss reading the documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches.  The first requires perhaps more tolerance for "noisy" notation.  Note that I did not use a vector argument.  If you must, the notation will be correspondingly "noisier".

```
Clear[f, x, y]
Dt[f[x, y]]
Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}].{dx, dy}
```